# How to update a cell based on the color of a cell on google sheets?

Tags: function, google-sheets, colors, format, cell

If the cell is of a specific color, then I want it to output value in a separate cell.

Not really sure how to define the function of cellcolor/something similar.

For example:

```
=IF(CELLcolour(K2)=22,"Y","N")
```

Comment: Google sheets or Excel? If not excel don’t tag it.

Comment: to play with bacground color you either need script or addon

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using scripts. Go to Tools > Script editor and use this code:

`function getCellColor(x) {
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  formula = formula.substring(formula.indexOf("(")+1, formula.indexOf(")"));
  color = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getSheet().getRange(formula).getBackground();
  return color;
 }`

Then you can use the formula to get background color of cells
`=getCellColor(A1)` in your Google Sheet. This will only work on a cell and not a range.

Comment: the cell just says "Loading" and it never gives an output

Comment: Can you share an editable demo spreadsheet with me where you are getting this error?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zp1PM6Pc9hIBLkNEPP-bQLcoG_dp47xW_Dyu_UpU5EU/edit?usp=sharing
So it loaded successfully and gave the color code

Comment: Great. If it worked for you then please accept the answer above.